# Confusion on the cp command when creating a new directory

Tags: directory, cp

Let me explain my problem with a simpler scenario. We have these two directories: `~/Foo` and `~/Bar`. Foo contains the files `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`. If I run the command `cp -R Foo Bar`, the Bar directory now contains a Foo folder containing the two text files. However, if I run the command `cp -R Foo Bar` when the `Bar` directory does not yet exist before the command is run, the newly created `Bar` directory will not contain a `Foo` subdirectory but only the two `.txt` files.

Why is it when I run the command in the first situation that it creates a subdirectory with the two files but in the second situation it just copies the two files into the new directory? Is the `cp` program supposed to function in this way?

Answer (score 4):

The command `cp Foo Bar` says "Copy the `Foo` directory to `Bar`".  If it already exists, it will put `Foo` inside of `Bar`.  If you want explicitly to copy the *contents* of `Foo`, use `cp -r Foo/ Bar/` or, better, use `rsync -a`.  To elaborate: if `Bar` does not exist, it *will* be created wtih `cp`; if it does not, it will act as the destination into which you want to copy files.